# iOS9.2.1 not supports for websites using AngularJS v1.3.2

Tags: angularjs, ios9.2.1

I am using AngularJS v1.3.2 + CodeIgniter for my website.

This is a responsive website.

It works for all browsers as well as Android devices. Also It works on iOS8.4 (Mobile). But It does not work on iOS9.2.1 or later (Mobile).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does "won't work" mean?  are you  getting some sort of error?

Comment: It is not displays content which are write in  "{{......}}"  i.e.{{ value.categoryId}} on html page

Answer (score 0):

Try to add iOS9 Patch from [here](https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c)
Probably there is problem with iOS9.

Regards